# Higher order function middleware for multiple authentication middlewares in express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a middleware that receives one or more middlewares, and returns a middleware.

```
const auth1 = (req, res, next) => {
  if (condition1) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Authentication required.');
  }
}

const auth2 = (req, res, next) => {
  if (condition2) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Authentication required.');
  }
}

app.use(anyof(auth1, auth2))
```

My first idea was below, but it stops to proceeding to the next middleware because `currentMiddleware` directly handle `res` and send a response on rejection, which terminates request handling. I thought if I pass a dummy res class to current middleware, I might make it, but I'm struggling.

```
type ExpressMiddleware = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => Promise<void> | void;

export const anyof = (
  ...middlewares: ExpressMiddleware[]
): ExpressMiddleware => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    let index = 0;
    const nextMiddleware = async () => {
      if (index >= middlewares.length) {
        return res.status(403).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
      }

      const currentMiddleware = middlewares[index++];
      try {
        await currentMiddleware(req, res, (err?: any) => {
          if (err) {
            nextMiddleware();
          } else if (res.headersSent) {
            return;
          } else {
            next();
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        if (!res.headersSent) {
          nextMiddleware();
        }
      }
    };
    await nextMiddleware();
  };
};
```

Obviously, I can just make one middleware, but I came here for help because I believe HOC makes source code more organized. Thanks.